# How to Determine encoding/compression of the string which appears like characters are dancing in gangam style

Tags: encoding, compression, base64, http-post, string-decoding

While analyzing  the HTTP Requests OF a website. I found that in one of the POST request it sends three postdata to  the server the first one was SAML data first base64 encoded then urlencoded.
But I am not able to figure out the value of other two postvars. One thing I am sure about is that it is not using any encryption methods like md5 or sha1 etc. COZ the response text contains my user name value which according to my research is neither stored in session variable or cookies means this encoding of post data can be reversed. So I am guessing that may be my  user name "RAHUL" is  inside one of these post variables. But am unable to read it.

First String:

> sRrWj1zUsisp/UylJiEf/pekY//ok1nYAAcvJfkxL9kMEggMAX0jTTs1hPPKTU9d1u/qgdq6eIvS
>   nk3NT6KkR9bKiGyQKY5iJ39JXGNlBvxs3F9N7TMHUBeNZ2BSDg05dTyYtdiVffRDnQ5KgDCy7ZjG
>   Lzj5J3x3LJumTau7aFc5CZ2b4xqzEPc4kGVcg/6l5D7Hxonp6U/0DnIzemcrXfb95X40CidNmz1J
>   PlGaeZzgAsA619vhs3AlGPNZ/Nbbm7IsJlVcKY6TvigrP0jMCp/0BvYb45gztvaJicN43JrNUsgc
>   +CLKaTvxflkLhul/sAe5Gbm83AtR/kNKQZf2hg==

Second String:

> Og5+F9RTHNs7NqUEYpgGSshInxZQzCP3gU2fkI8VnS60Ce2hmurlTLn6IcdP63zUkrDbdA2/+J00
>   DNgD15yW2lNo5Zi3PdfEEOxFjw8L5/RFwoIrMzTzS8csZaWqSAfqW1GiE4hbpAgeKZ4pXrmTLy2A
>   /AfT90uCptaoEa19qzD6/5o2+G4lCeJf5ZUMeZRMLvX3U909TlzCggf9KsHeJpfXGnGEefu9o0V9
>   kbQ5FzLEuao9ByCnXaFBEcDBDAFljrK0fsqJyLyv2gnhj4IOcCAEowa9N6tBsu/ngac9uR+NHY4+
>   r4l67i+nt5CRZ9PRLq/hT2qCoy6PguhDOEHbgg==

When I decoded the above strings using base64 decoder it returns unreadable value. I want to know what to do next so as to get useful data inside it.

I am pasting the complete post request including Headers and form data.

**HEADERS**

> Host: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
>
> Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Referer:xxx.xxx.com/xxxxxx/adsf
>
> Cookie: _abc_abc_session=1032510200e6bf9a8ae265553120e1ca;
>   AWSELB=F7610D8306188BFF856DC4E8C0134950D9FBEC546F2ACFBA970F103CC9E2B9074253115B0BB906564BB68191596A2637A0D1F52106813C785600B014A199891F5B8C6C8420
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Content-Length: 8725

**FORM**

> TARGET: www.XXVVVVVVVVVF.com/sessions/consume
>
> SAMLResponse: XXXXXXXXXX
>
> APID: ap_00001
>
> pca_red74:
>   **KiiYkBzqSHEKWu2Q//CgZg47iEBSOkU1Ew3yaUIAQNqHAf8AwZVLQXdNw5ZF0B67WJH46JDKQ/sP
>   Cypp2sofHA/Eq0gXMoH7yZt3RG0LXTuNANYNr/chOx4kks0/fINjpowPXTiSkWc0bsXimWH62BZy
>   mq7TATEsXM6w4ywu1cVTP+/DlfNy3Mf0V3VVwEjMWwtR/3X8zKgtRJKMTtwe/YGhus6YefSEknPO
>   pO9oy3zdDy0Yp7qRp93tPAdxRSXyIsJs5bJlefH8o5QSzsk7hlBhQFhd/OlKpMCsYMDSOHa+FJ1K
>   AqEWgH0eMzczO6LFhVdhAAm3DFaAvxL4u+DkuQ==**
>
> pca_red75:
>
> **tU48SalKFzVys9fZR1Se+5xP1dlOh9SlbYBT/Ct6BGiyIFEVEdyq2XR7BDuz/0BAsMfGwhgwI3Ws
>   uNk6KnEyOBIX+9u0eFer/VoHkGydw8310fGxJiiq13BYHnkzk9OLZCdD43VF27a6SvEtaA/LXnm4
>   ZrURgpoFWtfBmaC4zIkHkYgXW5wTYeJ1Ze0rgmBYPFlms2BefeRricA68NR3OsbSoCmwIKfuWe+2
>   esM4RN8t9jG/nccM2EeluDXRKJHA09O02Lq7KBhZw5o2OBCQ7nDc9p47Poli0as1yo+ylHfjJOag
>   qCeVuPBCLEwpJL74CreuzJGAYqSOVA9BOx5SQA==**

Comment: The == is typical for base64 encoding.

Comment: You provide not enough information, for example the HTTP headers and the original POST would be illuminating too. So I guess your question is ill-posed.

Comment: Every 3 bytes you need to encode as Base64 are converted to 4 ASCII characters and the '=' character is used to pad the result so that there are always a multiple of 4 encoded characters.

If you have an exact multiple of 3 bytes then you will get no equal sign.

One spare byte means you get two '=' characters at the end.

Two spare bytes means you get one '=' character at the end.

Therefore, your two '=' characters mean your number of bytes mod 3 (N % 3)is equal to 1.

I have seen some Base64 encoding that do not pad as is required by the specification.